# I have (if(e.repeat) return) in a function. I press+hold key1. No repeat. I press+hold key2. No repeat. I release key1. key2 repeats

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, keydown

I have a function called on keydown events.

I have `if(e.repeat) return` at the start of that function to prevent the rest of it running if I hold down a given key down.

So I press and hold key1. No repeat.
I press and hold key2. No repeat.
I release key1. Key2 repeats.

Also: I press and hold key1. No repeat.
I press and hold key2. No repeat.
I press and hold key3. No repeat.
I press and hold keys4 - 10 (because I only have 10 fingers) without releasing any of the keys. No repeats.
I release any of the keys. Key 10 repeats every time I release any other key.

Conversely, if I release key 10 before releasing any of the other keys: no repeat.

What's happening to make the last key that I press+hold to repeat when I release previously held keys and how do I stop it? I'm clearly missing something, but I have no idea what.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', pressKey)

function pressKey(e) {
  if (e.repeat) return
  console.log(`press key ${e.key}`)
}
```

Comment: Does your keyboard have [n-key rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(keyboard))? This might be a hardware limitation.

Comment: Are you also getting intermediate `keyup` events for the one that you hold down?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Hm... I got rid of the repeatTracker log to make it easier to see repeat keys. So for example, now when I press and hold q, then press and hold w, then release q while still holding w, I'll see:   
Press key q.  
Press key w.  
Press key w.  
Even though I only pressed w once

Comment: @Bergi I'm not getting intermediate keyup events and I doubt I have n-key rollover since my keyboard is just my mid-range laptop's keyboard. I'm probably just tired so I'm not getting it, but how would n-key rollover affect things?

Comment: Without n-key rollover, your keyboard might not realise that you're still holding down the first key, and only find about it when you release the other key(s), in which case it will send another keydown event to the OS.

Comment: When I run this, I press and hold key1, it logs "press key key1". I also press and hold key2, it logs "press key key2". I release key1, and nothing is logged. I release key2, and nothing is logged. Experimenting with more keys held down, I was able to recreate the "last key held down fires `keydown` again, with `repeat` set to false" behavior. I would not call that "repeats" as that has a specific meaning in the spec. You may want to look at [MDN's description of auto-repeating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent#auto-repeat_handling).

Comment: @Bergi Oh~, ok, that makes sense. Thanks! So I guess I'll have to do something like keep an array of keys pressed and hack together my own solution to keep keys from repeating? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ok, that's fair. As you said, it's probably more of a "fires ```keydown``` again" rather than a ```repeat```. That said, I'm still not totally sure why it only fires a ```keydown``` on the last key pressed and not any others.

Comment: Sure, I'm curious too! Although, keyboards and the events they raise are oddities dating far back in computing history. As that link I sent in my last comment shows, some OS/framework/browser combinations send `keyup` events during repeats, so who knows? I just think the question could be clearer for potential answerers (and future seekers) if it was more precise in its language.